# Can I apply a second coat of stain if the first coat is still damp?

Tags: porch

I just finish staining the deck and now I want to put a second coat, but the wood looks like it's still damp. Can I put on a second coat?

Comment: How long has it been? What type of stain are you using? What do the instructions on the side of the container recommend?

Comment: it has been five days, since I put the first coat.  but it rain on Thursday and today its Saturday ,cloudy no rain in the forecast today